# Writing Data to Flash while working with U-Boot

Tags: u-boot

I encountered a problem while writing data to flash with u-boot. I have 256Mb flash, and I can't write second part of flash which 128 MB. Does anyone have any information about this topic? I'm using a custom board includes freescale p2041 microprocessor.

Comment: What happens when you try to read the second half? Do you get a trap, read a copy of the first half, or read all "F"s?

Comment: Also, where did you get the u-boot? If it's based on a P2041 reference board, how large is the flash on that board?

Comment: What command(s) are you using to write to flash? Are you trying to write all at once? If so, how much memory do you have?

Answer (score 0):

******Thank you reply DoxyLover & shibley.
1. Custom board which includes p2041 microprocessor, has 256 MByte NOR flash. Using a probe, I'm able to
write u-boot(.elf) the second half of NOR flash. There is not any problem with probe. I able to read to written data in u-boot. 
But the main problem is u-boot. I'm trying to write environment variables to second half of NOR flash but I can't. I write 
the environment variables second half of nor flash and enter saveenv which is u-boot command. It says that successful.                                              But when I restart the u-boot, data does not exist.
2. My configuration file belongs to custom board (../include/configs/customboard.h) has following option related with
   environment variable and flash

*#define CONFIG_ENV_IS_IN_FLASH 1* (it specifies that environment variable is in nor flash)
3. Also nor flash has one bank. It also defined in (../include/configs/customboard.h) as following
   *#define CONFIG_SYS_MAX_FLASH_BANKS 1* (number of banks)
4. Erase timeout and write timeout are also defined in  (../include/configs/customboard.h) as following
   *#define CONFIG_SYS_FLASH_ERASE_TOUT 60000*
   *#define CONFIG_SYS_FLASH_WRITE_TOUT 500*
5. LAW (local access window) configuration is specified below

*SET_LAW(FLASH_BASE, LAW_SIZE_256M, LAW_TRGT_IF_LBC)*
6. TLB (translation lookaside buffer) configuration is specified below

SET_TLB_ENTRY(1, FLASH_BASE, FLASH_BASE_PHYS, MAS3_SX|MAS3_SW|MAS3_SR, MAS2_W|MAS2_G, 0, 2, BOOKE_PAGESZ_256M, 1)******

Nor Flash is Micron PC28F00BM29EWHA